# How to get the right PHP output on HTML form select tag

Tags: php, html, forms, html-select

Here is the whole PHP-code I use, until

Flug:

everything works fine:

```
<?php echo "//Bestelldatum: " . date("d/m/Y"); ?>
<br>
<br>
<p>--------------------</p>
<strong>Kundendaten</strong><br>
<br>
<p>Vorname: <?php echo $_POST["firstname"];?><br></p>
<p>Nachname: <?php echo $_POST["lastname"];?><br></p>
<p>E-Mail: <?php echo $_POST["mail"];?><br></p>
<p>Telefon/Mobile: <?php echo $_POST["phone"];?><br></p>
<p>--------------------</p>
<p><strong>Wünsche/Bemerkungen: </strong><br></p>
<?php echo $_POST["text"];?>
<br>
<p>--------------------</p>
<strong>Wunschflug</strong><br>
<br>
<p>Flug:</p>
<?php
    echo $_POST["flight"];
?>
```

and my HTML-code (selcet tag only):

```
<select id="flight">
    <option value="Wahl" selected="selected">*Wählen Sie einen Flug*</option>
    <option value="Funflug">Funflug</option>
    <option value="Thermikflug">Thermikflug</option>
</select>
```

This is my last try I made on this one. I tried some other ways but it wont get me one of my options selected.

Answer (score 2):

Id doesn't get posted only names try this

```
 <select name="flight">
    <option value="Wahl" selected="selected">*Wählen Sie einen Flug*</option>
    <option value="Funflug">Funflug</option>
    <option value="Thermikflug">Thermikflug</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: thanks guys! i think that might wortk...but it seems that there is now another problem, because now( and today already before i changed code into your suggestion) something else is not working. so the whole form is empty at the moment when i test it...maybe i'll be back for that one..but first i'll try to fix it by myself. thanks again for your replies!

Comment: .hahahaha update...got it! as i told u all, i'm a beginner in php and so i just forgot to start my localhost first to check my changes in php ;) works perfectly with your solution! thanks